# unbind click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to unbind click event but it is not working with live method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').live('click',function(){
alert(0)
$(this).unbind('click')
})
})
</script>


<a href="#">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the die method:
http://api.jquery.com/die/

If you use 1.7:

```
$("p").live("click", foo); // ... now foo will be called when paragraphs are clicked ...
$("p").die("click", foo); // ... foo will no longer be called.
```

Indeed deprecated but it depends on the version you are using.

```
 version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click','#a',function(){

//Code here

});
```

live is depricated..use `on()` for `live()`

and use this for unbind

```
$("p").die("click", foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) instead:

```
$(document).one('click','a',function(){
   alert(0);       
});
```